# why does this line produce a runtime error?

Tags: vba, excel

Working with a code to grab specific data from files and this line:

```
With sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
```

produces: method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed.

I have sht dim'd as worksheet and am just trying to select the range as the whole sheet?

Comment: Did you set your sht to any worksheet? Can you please share the code completely, if not to level needed. When i ran .Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)). I didn't findany issues

Comment: Cells or Range without a qualifying worksheet will always refer to the active sheet, so your code will error if `sht` is not active

Comment: Expansion to what Tim has mentioned...would this correct it `sh.Range("A1").`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you "dim'd" sht as worksheet. I assume you are talking about

`Dim sht As Worksheet`

If you did not do the following, there might be the problem:

`set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("insertnamehere")` [the ThisWorkbook. part asumes the worksheet is at the same workbook as the code]

If that does not solve your Problem, pls make a debugoutput (I prefere MsgBox, but only personal preference) of the second part, like `MsgBox sht.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address` and post the result here (An address? A new error? If so, wich?)

Hope it helps at least one step forward.

PS: If you set sht allready (not only dim'd it <- love that phrase :P ) pls also edit your post and add the code for that (and anything that might relate)